# $_SESSION variables not persisting on a server behind a proxy/load balancer

Tags: php, session, proxy, load-balancing

I am having alot of trouble using $_SESSION variables on my PHP application. Everything worked correctly if I directly access the web server that is running the PHP application. However in production, the web server hosting the PHP application is actually behind a proxy/load balancer. The architecture is this:

AWS Load Balancer -> composed of 2 identical proxy servers -> each proxy server simply forwards the request to a backend server -> the backend server actually executes and runs the PHP application

The reason that this had to be done in production is because of a requirement to have specific URLs in the browser.

I have already put these on all the relevant pages:

```
session_start();
header('p3p: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"');
```

Could this forwarding of requests be causing the $_SESSION variables to not persist?

I don't understand, the backend server is doing everything anyway, the $_SESSION variables should be persisting the backend server and the proxy server just forwards/receive requests from the backend server without doing anything??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the load balancer is configured to use a persistent backend server for each client. By default, each backend server has its own session data, so if a user switches to a different backend server, it won't have the session variablkes that were assigned on the other server.

Either that or you need to implement shared session storage between all the backend servers.

Comment: though there are 2 proxies, only 1 backend server, so in theory, no matter which proxy server gets the request, both of them forward to the same backend server. Can this still impact $_SESSION variables?